# How can i hide a logo from the left menu in antdesign pro layout in blazor

Tags: c#-3.0, ant-design-blazor

This is the tag
<AntDesign.ProLayout.BasicLayout Logo="@("assets/logo.svg")" MenuData="_menuData">
When i remove the logo parameter like this:
<AntDesign.ProLayout.BasicLayout MenuData="_menuData">

I get a broken image link like this:
[Broken image src link after remove the logo parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGxIM.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logo cannot be removed in Ant Design Pro Layout According to their source code,

[image]

But you can write CSS styles to hide that. Add this style after the <AntDesign.ProLayout.BasicLayout/> tag to your Razor component

```
<style>
    #logo img {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Now you can get a output like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks much Fernando,  this has worked for me. Is it possible i can hide the text on the logo too (Ant Design Pro)

Comment: Yes, you can hide or change the logo text @MartinKatumba. Can you mark my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

```
<AntDesign.ProLayout.BasicLayout Logo="@("./YOUR PATH/logo.png")" Title="LEAVE EMPTY OR ADD SITE NAME"  MenuData="_menuData">
```